# Corda Accounts - Transaction between Account and a Host Node

Tags: java, corda

**Consider a scenario where their is a PartyA and account1 is created in PartyA. Now we have to initiate a transaction between account1 and PartyA. Is it possible to have a transaction flow initiated by an account and receiving party is a host node? If yes, can anyone please suggest what will be required steps to be taken coding wise. If there is a sample example, then please let me know.**

Answer (score 0):

1. A flow is always started by a node (i.e. Party), not by an account.
2. But, a node can sign a transaction on behalf of an account using the account's `PublicKey`; and that's what you're looking for.
3. Your example simplifies this task since the account is hosted on the same node that starts the flow; so you don't need a responder flow.

So things will look this way:

1. `PartyA` initiates your flow.
2. I assume that you have a state where one of the fields is an account; let's assume it's:

```
MyState(myAccount: PublicKey)
```

3. Your flow will have as an input parameter the `UUID` of `myAccount`:

```
class MyFlow(val myAccountId: UUID, ...
```

4. You will first query the vault to fetch the account using its UUID:

```
val myAccountInfo = accountService.accountInfo(myAccountId)
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("Can't find account with Id $myAccountId")
```

5. Request a new key for the account:

```
val myAccountKey = subFlow(RequestKeyForAccount(myAccountInfo.state.data)).owningKey
```

6. Create your state:

```
val myState = MyState(myAccountKey)
```

7. Now the most important part, the command that creates your state will require 2 signatures: `PartyA`'s (which is the node that initiated the flow, i.e. `ourIdentity`), and the signature of `myAccountInfo`:

```
val command = Command(MyState.Commands.Create(), 
              listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey, myAccountKey))
```

8. I'm skipping some steps, but when the time comes to sign the transaction; you will sign it with the key of `PartyA` (i.e. the initiator of the flow which is `ourIdentity`) and the key of `myAccountInfo`:

```
val fullySignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, 
                    listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey, myAccountKey))
```

You can have a look at the IOU example which is implemented using **Accounts Library**; again, in your case you don't need a responder flow; they created a responder flow in case the `borrower` account was hosted on a different node than the initiating node.
See example [here](https://github.com/opticyclic/corda-accounts-demo/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/github/opticyclic/corda/demo/flows/accounts/IOUAccountFlow.kt).